# @Transactional : Is there a way that hibernate can persist child transacttion when parent fails

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactional

I am new in Spring-Hibernate and my issue is : **a transaction is not saving the data in the table. But not throwing any exception as well.** From the line

```
Long id = logTransactionFileUpload(fileMetdataBean);
```

in the function "logClientFile" (in the "Transactional" annotated class/service class, listed below), **I am seeing a returned id but data did not show up in the table.** .

F**inding is :** this is nested transaction and was rolled back as the parent had exception from "msgProducer.send( message, jmsConnectInfo )" in JobRunnerServiceImpl class , in submitJob method- means after db insertion. **Is there a way that hibernate can persist child transacttion when parent fails?**

I am not suspecting my spring/hibernate configuration as save from other parts are working fine. Only this part is the problem.

**FYI:**

if I turn on ( in the DAO impl class, listed below)

```
 //getCurrentSession().flush();
//getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
```

Then data is showing up in the table.But this commit and flush should not be there when @transactional is used.

My @Transactional annotated class:

```
    @Service("jobRunnerService")
    @Transactional
    public class JobRunnerServiceImpl implements JobRunnerService
    {
        private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger( MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass() );



        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("fileLoggerDao")
        private IFileLoggerDAO fileLoggerDAO;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("fileMetaDataDao")
        private IGenericDAO<FileMetaDataBean,Long> fileMetaDataDAO;



        public void submitJob(String serviceName, String filePath, long clientId, long layoutId, String audienceId,
                boolean isCA) 
        {

            Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();

            try
            {
                ..... doing something............

                LOG.info( "Logging file information in FILE_META_DATA table... " );
                String loggedFile = logClientFile( fileName, FACEBOOK_FILE_TYPE, fileExt, clientId, tpList );

               ..... doing something............


                LOG.info( " Submitting job to JMS Q...." );
                msgProducer.send( message, jmsConnectInfo );    

                //test code for the receiver to see if sent messages are received by receiver
                //WildFlyJmsQueueReceive receiver = new WildFlyJmsQueueReceive();
                //receiver.receiveMessagesFromQueue();

            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                String msg = "Error in JobRunnerServiceImpl.submitJob";
                LOG.error(msg,e);
                throw new RuntimeException(msg,e);
            }

        }



        private String logClientFile( String fileName, String fileType, String fileExt, long clientId, List<ToolkitPropertyBean> tpList )        
        {
            ApplicationEnvironment enviro;

            try
            {
                ..... doing something............


                //insert record in FILE_META_DATA table
                FileMetaDataBean fileMetdataBean = new FileMetaDataBean(fileId, new Long(fileTypeID), fileName, fbFilePickUpDir +java.nio.file.FileSystems.getDefault().getSeparator()+ currentFile.getName(), receivedDate,new Long( FileUtilities.getRecordCount( currentFile ) ).longValue(), clientId);
                Long id = logTransactionFileUpload(fileMetdataBean);
                return null;
            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                String msg = "Inside JobRunnerServiceImpl.logClientFile  - Unable to log client file";
                LOG.error(msg,e);
                throw new RuntimeException(msg,e);
            }

        }

        private Long logTransactionFileUpload(FileMetaDataBean bean)
        {
            return (Long)fileMetaDataDAO.save(bean);
        }


    }
```

**My bean :**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="FILE_META_DATA", schema = "OAP_META_OWNER", uniqueConstraints = {
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "file_meta_data_id"),
             })
    //@SequenceGenerator(name="file_meta_seq", sequenceName="file_meta_seq")
    public class FileMetaDataBean implements Serializable
    {

        private long fileMetaDataId;
        private Long fileType;
        private String fileName;
        private String originaFileName;
        private Date receivedDt;
        private Long recordCount;
        private Long clientId;

        public FileMetaDataBean(){}

        public FileMetaDataBean( long fileMetaDataId, Long fileType, String fileName, String originaFileName, Date receivedDt,
                long recordCount, long clientId )
        {
            super();
            this.fileMetaDataId = fileMetaDataId;
            this.fileType = fileType;
            this.fileName = fileName;
            this.originaFileName = originaFileName;
            this.receivedDt = receivedDt;
            this.recordCount = recordCount;
            this.clientId = clientId;
        }

        @Id
    //  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "file_meta_seq")
        @Column(name = "file_meta_data_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        public long getFileMetaDataId()
        {
            return fileMetaDataId;
        }

        public void setFileMetaDataId( long fileMetaDataId )
        {
            this.fileMetaDataId = fileMetaDataId;
        }

         @Column(name = "file_type_id", unique = false, nullable = false)
        public Long getFileType()
        {
            return fileType;
        }

        public void setFileType( Long fileType )
        {
            this.fileType = fileType;
        }

        @Column(name = "file_name", unique = false, nullable = false)
        public String getFileName()
        {
            return fileName;
        }

        public void setFileName( String fileName )
        {
            this.fileName = fileName;
        }

        @Column(name = "original_file_name", unique = false, nullable = false)
        public String getOriginaFileName()
        {
            return originaFileName;
        }

        public void setOriginaFileName( String originaFileName )
        {
            this.originaFileName = originaFileName;
        }

        @Column(name = "received_dt", unique = false, nullable = false)
        public Date getReceivedDt()
        {
            return receivedDt;
        }

        public void setReceivedDt( Date receivedDt )
        {
            this.receivedDt = receivedDt;
        }

         @Column(name = "record_count", unique = false, nullable = false)
        public Long getRecordCount()
        {
            return recordCount;
        }

        public void setRecordCount( Long recordCount )
        {
            this.recordCount = recordCount;
        }

        @Column(name = "client_id", unique = false, nullable = false)    
        public Long getClientId()
        {
            return clientId;
        }

        public void setClientId( Long clientId )
        {
            this.clientId = clientId;
        }

    }
```

**The DAO interface**

```
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

    public interface IGenericDAO< Entity extends Serializable, ID extends Serializable >
    {

        Entity getById( ID id );

        List<Entity> getAll();

        List<Entity> getAll( String contraints);

        List<Entity> search( Map<String, Object> parms );

        ID save( Entity entity );

        void saveOrUpdate( Entity entity );

        void update( Entity entity );

        void delete( Entity entity );

        void deleteById( ID id );

        void setSessionFactory( SessionFactory sessionFactory );

        void setEntity( final Class clazz );

    }
```

The DAO impl:

```
    @SuppressWarnings(value = "unchecked")
    public class GenericDAOImpl<Entity extends Serializable, ID extends Serializable>
            implements IGenericDAO<Entity, ID> {

        protected Class<Entity> clazz;

        public GenericDAOImpl(Class<Entity> clazz) {
            System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " called");
            this.clazz = clazz;
        }

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("sessionFactory")
        protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        @Override
        public Entity getById(ID id) {
            System.out.println("GenericHibernateDAO.getById called with id: " + id);
            return (Entity) getCurrentSession().get(clazz, id);
        }

        @Override
        public List<Entity> getAll() {
            System.out.println("GenericHibernateDAO.getAll called");

            return getCurrentSession().createCriteria(clazz.getName()).list();


    //      return getCurrentSession().createQuery("from " + clazz.getName()).list();
        }

        @Override
        public List<Entity> getAll(String contraints) {
            System.out.println("GenericHibernateDAO.getAll called. Constraint : " + contraints);
            return getCurrentSession().createQuery("from " + clazz.getName() + " " + contraints ).list();
        }

        @Override
        public List search(Map<String, Object> parms) {
            Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(clazz);

            for (String field : parms.keySet()) {
                criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike(field, parms.get(field)));
            }
            return criteria.list();
        }

        @Override
        public ID save(Entity entity) {
            Serializable id = null;
            try
            {
                id =  getCurrentSession().save(entity);
            }
            catch(RuntimeException e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
    //      getCurrentSession().flush();
    //      getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();

            return (ID)id;

        }

        @Override
        public void saveOrUpdate(Entity entity) {
            getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
            getCurrentSession().flush();
            getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
        }

        @Override
        public void update(Entity entity) {
            getCurrentSession().update(entity);
            getCurrentSession().flush();
            getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
        }

        @Override
        public void delete(Entity entity) {
            getCurrentSession().delete(entity);
            getCurrentSession().flush();
            getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
        }

        @Override
        public void deleteById(ID id) {
            delete(getById(id));
        }

        protected Session getCurrentSession() {

            // return sessionFactory.openSession();
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }

        @Override
        public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        }

        @Override
        public void setEntity(final Class clazz) {
            this.clazz = clazz;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried moving `@Transactional` from class to method level ? Are you expecting, when execution of `logClientFile` finishes there should be an entry in DB (visible) prior to completion of `submitJob` method ? I was also facing same issue when I am trying to run long task in a single transaction. You are able to get `id` bcoz an entry is inserted in DB but, since your transaction is still in progress, you are unable to see entry in DB. You have add `@Transactional` on class, it means all methods in that class are in transaction. Check DB once execution of your program completed.

Comment: You are right.this is nested transaction and was rolled back as the parent had exception from "msgProducer.send( message, jmsConnectInfo )" in JobRunnerServiceImpl  class , in submitJob method- means after db insertion.Hence rolled back. Was wondering if there is a way to persist the child transaction even if the parent fails.

Comment: Add `@Transactional` annotation to method level & try with `propagation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the

> noRollbackFor

property of Transactional annotation something like e.g.  `@Transactional(noRollbackFor=SendMsgFailureException.class)`. You need to handle the exception of the parent caller method for which you indent not to rollback.

Comment: tried with @Transactional(noRollbackFor=FileMetaDataBean.class) in the class level for JobRunnerServiceImpl class. It did not work.

Comment: for your case you have to put @Transactional at method level as your method would be throwing the exception for which you would like not to rollback.Also "noRollbackFor" should always be for exception class not your service class

Comment: Thanks mhasan. It worked after adding @Transactional(noRollbackFor=RuntimeException.class) at the method level where it was getting the runtime exception.